# SQL Server Query for Partitioning Data

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, partition

I have a requirement of assigning sequential Numbers to students. The problem is the data must be partitioned by course first and then the Number must be assigned starting from say 1 to say 1000.

Each Course should have at least a gap of say 20 ( may differ ) to accommodate a student in the same course in case, someone, if left out as of now appears later.

[image]

and so on.

I have tried partitioning and Recursive CTE but haven't succeeded to get this kind of series for assigning finally the RollNumber.

Any help would be very much anticipated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in two steps with a subquery. First get your `row_number()` partitioned by `course` and order by `student id`, then you can bump each partition by `20` by counting the previous `1` values returned by your `row_number()` and multiplying by 20.

```
SELECT
    s_no, 
    course, 
    rownumber + (SUM(CASE WHEN rownumber = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY course, s_no ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) * 20) - 20
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            s_no, 
            course, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY course ORDER BY s_no) rownumber
        FROM test
    ) sub
ORDER BY course, s_no;


+------+--------+-----------+
| s_no | course | rownumber |
+------+--------+-----------+
|    1 | A      |         1 |
|    2 | A      |         2 |
|    3 | A      |         3 |
|    1 | B      |        21 |
|    2 | B      |        22 |
|    3 | B      |        23 |
|    1 | C      |        41 |
|    2 | C      |        42 |
|    3 | C      |        43 |
+------+--------+-----------+
```

This isn't exactly as your desired output, but I think it's the same as what you are after. You can monkey with the math in that main query though and bump each partitions starting position to whatever you want.

Comment: THANK YOU @Jnevill. I will try and report back. thanks again.

Comment: Works like a charm. Can you please help me get a number for next course as a multiple of 10 and greater than 20 instead as of just adding 20 alone.